# requests_html does not render javascript webpages

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests-html

Why my code doesn't render the javascript pages using requests_html and beautifulSoup

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = HTMLSession()


def track(num):
    url = f'https://www.trackingmore.com/track/en/{num}'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0'}
    r = session.post(url,headers=headers)
    # r.html.render(timeout=20)
    res = []
    soup =  BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
    st = soup.find('div',class_ ="track-status uk-flex")
    print(st.text)
    if st != 'Not Found':
        checkpoint = soup.find_all('div', class_="info-checkpoint")
        for i in checkpoint:
            date = i.find('div',class_='info-date').text.strip()
            desc = i.find('div',class_='info-desc').text.strip()
            res.append({
                    'Date':date.replace('\xa0','')[:19],
                    'Description':desc.replace('\xa0','')
                    })
        return res
    else :
        return res
```

The output is like this, I can't get the value inside of each javascript function

```
[{'Date': '{{info.Date}} {{inf', 'Description': '{{info.StatusDescription}}'}, {'Date': '{{info.Date}} {{inf', 'Description': '{{info.StatusDescription}}'}]
```